# Deploying bottle.py Apps

Tags: python, cgi, bottle

I've had success running apps created with bottle.py on localhost, and I'm trying to deploy one to my school's contributed webserver. Unfortunately, I'm not really sure where to start. I know that bottle.py has an option to package an app as a cgi app, but that's about it. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean WSGI not CGI? Read bottle's doc first, and then check gunicorn for wsgi server

Comment: Thanks for the advice. My school already provided a server for the app to run on, so I ended up not needing gunicorn. All I needed was a way to package an app written with Bottle so that it could be run as a CGI script on a preexisting server. It turns out that Bottle has a nice option for this (in the Bottle run function, give the keyword-arg "server=CGIServer").

Comment: use CGI is okay if you just want it to *work*. python frameworks usually runs better (in performance) with WSGI server. Anyway, congrats.